# firefox only: TypeError: toggler is undefined

Tags: mootools, accordion

I've cobbled together some mootools accordion code that worked for a couple of years but suddenly I notice that firefox breaks it -- no problem in safari, chrome or IE.

http://jordanrossfilms.com

console shows: TypeError: toggler is undefined here:

toggler.setStyle('color', '#666');

I imagine that its something very simple, yet for this newbie, I have no idea what is going on  to cause this? Any help? Complete code below:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
var myAccordion = new Accordion($('accordion'), 'h1.toggler', 'div.element', {
    display: -1,
    opacity: true,
    alwaysHide: true,
    onActive: function(toggler, element){
        toggler.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was inactive
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {
          //...
        });
    },
    onBackground: function(toggler, element){
        toggler.setStyle('color', '#666');

        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was active
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

        toggler.addEvent('mouseleave',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#666');

        });

        });
    }

});
```

var myAccordion2 = new Accordion($('accordion2'), 'h4.toggler', 'div.element2', {
        display: -1,
        opacity: true,
        alwaysHide: true,
        onActive: function(toggler, element){
            toggler.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

```
        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was inactive
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {
          //...
        });
    },
    onBackground: function(toggler, element){
        toggler.setStyle('color', '#666');

        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was active
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

        toggler.addEvent('mouseleave',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#666');

        });

        });
    }

});

var myAccordion = new Accordion($('accordion3'), 'h5.toggler', 'div.element3', {
    display: -1,
    opacity: true,
    alwaysHide: true,
    onActive: function(toggler, element){
        toggler.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was inactive
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {
          //...
        });
    },
    onBackground: function(toggler, element){
        toggler.setStyle('color', '#666');

        //remove the toggler hover events to clear out its events when it was active
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseenter');
        toggler.removeEvents('mouseleave');

        //then add your events again
        toggler.addEvent('mouseenter',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#df1a00');

        toggler.addEvent('mouseleave',function()
        {this.setStyle('color', '#666');

        });

        });
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using mootools 1.2
mootools recently post a fix to 1.2 causing error in firefox because of new firefox and mootools collide with String.concat.

You can see a [Blog Post](http://mootools.net/blog/2013/02/19/mootools-1-2-6-released/) about it. 
Anyway try to update to the new 1.2 version and see if it's solves the problem

Comment: Just tried that and site completely breaks in all browsers. Firefox shows this error: ReferenceError: Accordion is not defined

ReferenceError: Accordion is not defined
 

var myAccordion = new Accordion($('accordion'), 'h1.toggler', 'div.element', {

Comment: Accordion is defined in mootools more [http://mootools.net/more125](http://mootools.net/more125). Did you download it as well ? check what previous used in mootools and dl all toghether

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that. Added in all the elements with more and it's working again.

Comment: Id'e be happy to get the score then ^^

Comment: tried to vote you up, but my reputation just isn't enough! checked your answer though. thanks again.